# NextJS - Is there no way to run server-side queries in components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm aware we can use `getInitialProps`, or `getServerSideProps` from a page to query things on the server.

In Gatsby (I know, static vs SSR), we can use `useStaticQuery`, in PHP everything is server-side.
In NextJS is it completely impossible to query things within components on the server?

I can't find any documentation around it. If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

Is `getStaticProps` what you are actually looking for?
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: Mmmnot quite - I'm more asking whether we can run _server-side_ queries from within components (e.g query for menu items within my `Header` component). 

All the `getXProps` functions only work at page-level. Seems bizarre you can't do SSR queries anywhere else.

Comment: Ah now I see! Sorry I think I missed your point there. 

I don't think that's supported, hopefully I'm wrong though.